# Inspect optimized vs. unoptimized JS from v8

Tags: javascript, assembly, v8

As an educational exercise, I'd like to inspect disassembled JS generated by V8, and compare both the optimized and unoptimized versions to see what changes and what doesn't.

In Vyacheslav Egorov's JSConf 2012 excellent slides (http://s3.mrale.ph/jsconf2012.pdf) he recommends compiling V8 like so:

```
make ia32.release objectprint=on \
  disassembler=on

out/ia32.release/d8 --print-opt-code \
  --code-comments \
  --trace-hydrogen \
  test.js
```

which will enable the disassembler for introspection by the curious.

However, the talk is from 2012, so I have a few questions:

1. Is this the best way of doing things? How do I generate the *unoptimized* JS versus the *optimized* JS for test.js in this example? Is it possible to hook into that and/or disable the optimizer in v8?
2. Likewise, is Hydrogen still relevant to disassembling the code if all I want to do is inspect the final disassembly? My understanding is that [TurboFan will be replacing it soon](https://codereview.chromium.org/426233002), for example.